# binary tree deletion saying null pointer

Tags: java

so far i made my binary tree it can add nodes u can select which parent u want to add a child node but the problem is whrnever i delete a node it does delete it and sometimes it say null pointer exception and when i show my nodes it still there. this is my deletetion method:

```
   public void delete(Node node){ 
        if (node! =null) { 
            if(node.value.equals(nodeToDelete)) { 
                node=null;
            } 
            delete(node.left); 
            delete(node.right); 
            }
        }
    }
```

i already define my node, my add method, and the nodeToDelete is a string and thats all.tnx in advance

Comment: Next time you ask, format your code so it is readable. I have done it now for you, but please do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Im sorry im just running out of time

Comment: Which line the `NPE` comes from and is it a single thread program ?

Comment: There are several problems with this code. You should review how a node in a binary tree can be deleted. Btw, is it a search tree?

Answer (score 0):

`sometimes it say null pointer exception`. I think your `NPE` was thrown when only your `node` didn't have a value.

You need to review your code here, how did you define your `value` ?

```
if(node.value.equals(nodeToDelete)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you delete your node and then you try to delete its children. This causes null pointer exception. First, you have to delete the children and then you delete the node.

I think that the delete operation in binary tree is slightly more complicated. You should consider 3 different cases:

- The node is a leaf
- The node has one child
- The node has two children

Please read the [Wikipedia article about binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Deletion) and try to re-implement it.

Answer (score 0):

When you first set a node to null and then access parts of this node, a NPE is statically foreseeable - so, first delete the children and then set the node itself to null.